# Add New Data in Text File by ASM 8086 (Dosbox)

Tags: assembly, emu8086, dosbox

Yo Guys, i want a data added in a text file by ady be create and also some previous data in the text file. The tutorial that i found are just replace the front word/data.

i want to add a new data in the text file that the new data is after the previous data. After the program , the new data must at the last line of the text file and the previous data are still there.

My idea is to use int 21h,42h to hold the buffer when reading the file and int 21h ,40h to write the data in text file. But i still not idea how to do. Is it use those both function ? If yes then how to do it ?

---

Example :

**Before (test.txt):**

Banana$

**After Program (if i want add "Banana" in):**

BananaBanana$

---

Thanks and hope u guys have a great day !

Comment: Service `42h, int 21h` moves file pointer inside a file. So move file pointer to the end of a file and append new data. `ah = 42h`, `mov al,2`, `mov cx,0`, `mov dx,0`, `int 21h`.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had a little bit fun today with this assignment. ;) I applied few file services `int 21h`:

`5bh` - Create file for reading or writing 
`3dh` - Open file
`42h` - Move file pointer to calculate file size
`40h` - Write to file and screen
`3eh` - Close file

```
.286
.model small
.stack 0ffh

.data
    file_name           db 'file.txt',0 ; The name of the file

    inputSize           db 11           ; buffered input, ah = 0ah, int 21h, size 10 characters + enter
    inputChars          db 0            ; how many characters user inputed
    inputBuffer         db 11 dup(0)    ; space for characters  

    buffer              db 30 dup(0)    ; read from file and write data here
                                        
    buffer_size         dw 30           ; append up to 30 bytes
    memory_left         dw 30           ; do we have more space for data?
    file_handle         dw 0
    file_size           dw 0                
    array_4_value       db 5 dup('x')       
    
    file_status_msg     db "File status: ",'$'
    before              db "Data inside file: ",13,10,'$'
    file_error          db "<< Something is wrong with the file (ax = 2,3,4 or 5).",13,10,13,10,'$'
    file_exists         db "<< File already exists (ax = 80) >>",13,10,13,10,'$'
    file_success        db "<< File successfuly created >>",13,10,13,10,'$'
    file_open_error     db "<< Error opening the file (ax = 2,3,4,5,12) >>",13,10,13,10,'$'
    hdd_error_msg       db "Not enough memory. Sorry, can't append new data.",13,10,13,10,"Press any key to quit.",'$'
    free_mem            db "Free memory : ",'$' 
    bytes               db " byte(s) left.",13,10,13,10,'$' 
    line_30             db "------------------------------",13,10,'$'       
    data_added          db 13,10,"Data added successfuly. ",13,10,13,10,'$' 
    
    append_msg          db "Add text to file (max 10 characters): ",'$' 
    
    new_line            db 13,10,'$'    
    
.code
main:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    
;;---------------------------------------
;; Create the file for reading/writing

    mov ah,09h                  ; Print message "File status: " 
    lea dx, file_status_msg
    int 21h 

create_file:    
    mov ah, 5bh
    lea dx, file_name           ; file name asciiz  
    mov cx,0                    ; normal attributes                 
    int 21h
    jc create_error         ; error ?

    mov ah,09h                  ; Print message "<< File successfuly created >>"    
    lea dx, file_success
    int 21h 

;;---------------------------------------
;; Open the file for reading/writing
    
open_file:  
    mov ah, 3dh
    lea dx, file_name           ; file name asciiz  
    mov al,2                    ; read/write permission
    int 21h
    jc open_error               ; error ?
    
;;---------------------------------------
;; Save the file handle

handle:
    mov [file_handle], ax
    
;;---------------------------------------
;; Calculate file size

calculate_file_size:    
    mov ah,42h                  ; move file pointer
    mov bx, [file_handle]       ; file handle
    mov al,2                    ; move file pointer starting from end of the file   
    mov cx,0                    ; cx:dx = new pointer location, beginning of the file
    mov dx,0
    int 21h
    
;;---------------------------------------
;; Save file size   

    mov [file_size], ax         ; number of characters in file

;;---------------------------------------
;; Reset file pointer to start of the file

reset_and_read: 
    mov ah,42h                  ; move file pointer
    mov bx, [file_handle]       ; file handle
    mov al,0                    ; file pointer was at the end of the file now should be at the beginning    
    mov cx,0                    ; cx:dx = new pointer location, beginning of the file
    mov dx,0
    int 21h

;;---------------------------------------
;; Print file content

    mov ah,09h                  ; Print message "Data inside file before modification: "    
    lea dx, before
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,09h                  ; Print message "------"    
    lea dx, line_30
    int 21h 
    
read_service_3fh:
    mov ah,3fh                  ; read file or device
    mov cx, [buffer_size]       ; how many bytes to read
    mov bx, [file_handle]       ; file handle
    lea dx,buffer               ; where to read
    int 21h             

print_to_screen_service_40h:
    mov ah,40h                  ; write file or device
    mov cx, [buffer_size]       ; how many bytes to write
    mov bx, 1                   ; write to screen
    lea dx,buffer               ; what to write
    int 21h                     

    mov ah,09h                  ; move to new line
    lea dx, new_line
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,09h                  ; Print message "------"    
    lea dx, line_30
    int 21h 
    
    mov ah,09h                  ; move to new line
    lea dx, new_line
    int 21h     
;;---------------------------------------
;; Print how many more bytes we can add

    mov ah,09h                  ; Print message "Free memory : "    
    lea dx, free_mem
    int 21h

    mov ax,[file_size]
    mov bx,[buffer_size]
    sub bx,ax
    mov [memory_left],bx    
    mov ax,bx
    push ax
;;---------------------------------------------
;; This is probably worst part in the code :D
;; Just calculate how long is value and print digits    

    mov cl, 5           ; max value is 65535 so we need 5 characters                    
    mov ch, 0           
    mov bl, 10          
    mov di,offset array_4_value + 4
    
    bin_2_ascii:
        div bl
        cmp al, 0
        jz b2a_show 
        
        mov [di],ah
        dec di              
                
        mov ah, 0   
        dec cl
        jnz bin_2_ascii

    b2a_show:
        mov [di],ah
        
    mov si, offset array_4_value
    mov cx, 5
    
    b2a_print:      
        mov dl,[si]
        cmp dl,'x'
        jz skip
        mov ah,2
        add dl,30h
        int 21h

        skip:
            inc si
            dec cx
            jnz b2a_print
            
    mov ah,09h                  ; Print message " byte(s)"  
    lea dx, bytes
    int 21h 

    pop ax
    
    cmp ax,0
    jz mem_error

;;---------------------------------------
;; Add new data to file

    mov ah,09h                  ; Print message "Add text to file (max 10 characters): "    
    lea dx, append_msg
    int 21h

    mov ah,0ah                  ; user input
    lea dx, inputSize
    int 21h

disk_space: 
    mov ax,[file_size]
    add al,[inputChars]
    cmp ax,30
    jg mem_error

append_to_file_service_40h:
    mov ah,40h                  ; write file or device
    xor cx,cx
    mov cl, [inputChars]        ; how many bytes to write
    mov bx, [file_handle]       ; write to file
    lea dx,inputBuffer              ; what to write
    int 21h                     

    mov ah,09h                  ; move to new line
    lea dx, new_line
    int 21h 

    mov ah,09h                  ; Print message "Data dded."    
    lea dx, data_added
    int 21h     

    mov di, offset array_4_value
    mov cx, 5
    mov al, 'x'
    
    array_clear:        
        mov [di], al
        inc di
        loop array_clear

    jmp calculate_file_size

jmp_hlt:
hlt
jmp jmp_hlt 

mem_error:
    mov ah,09h                  ; move to new line
    lea dx, hdd_error_msg
    int 21h 
    
    mov ah,8
    int 21h
    jmp closeApp
    
        mov ah,40h                  ; reading file or device
        mov bx,1
        mov al,0                    ; move file pointer starting from begining of the file
        mov cx,[file_size]                  ; cx:dx, where to move pointer
        mov dx,0                    ; file_size, number of characters in file
        int 21h                     
    
    
create_error: 
    cmp ax,80
    jz file_already_exists

    mov ah,09h                      ; Print message "<< Something is wrong with the file (ax = 2,3,4 or 5)>>"   
    lea dx, file_error
    int 21h     
    jmp file_msg_done
    
    file_already_exists:
        mov ah,09h                  ; Print message "<< File already exists (ax = 80) >>"   
        lea dx, file_exists
        int 21h     
        
    file_msg_done:
  
    jmp open_file 

open_error: 
    mov ah,09h                  ; Print message "<< Error opening the file (ax = 2,3,4,5,12) >>"    
    lea dx, file_open_error
    int 21h     

closeApp:  
    mov ah, 3eh
    mov bx,[file_handle]
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h                   ; exit
    int 21h

end main
```

Comment: Nassau Bro, which school or college are u from ?

Comment: I finished schools long time ago. Why? I did something wrong?

Comment: ohh okkk noting hahaha